# Spring data redis, multi-threading issue with Jedis

Tags: multithreading, jedis, spring-data-redis

I am using redis in a heavily multi-threaded java application and getting intermittent `ClassCastException`s. Reading through various discussions seemed to point out this might be because the Jedis connection instance getting shared between multiple threads (https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/359). The solution suggested is to use JedisPool which is thread-safe.

I have configured redis through Spring redis support by using RedisTemplate. A thing to note is I am using multiple templates (to support different models for serialization and de-serialization). Here is snippet of my configuration -

```
<bean id="jedisConnFactory"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
      redis:usePool="true" redis:poolConfig-ref="jedisPoolConfig" redis:hostName="${redis.datasource.hostName}"
      redis:database="${redis.database.index}" redis:port="${redis.datastore.port}"/>

<bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${redis.conn.maxIdle}"/>
    <property name="maxTotal" value="${redis.conn.maxTotal}"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="${redis.conn.minIdle}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="redisTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
      redis:connectionFactory-ref="jedisConnFactory"
      redis:keySerializer-ref="redisStringSerializer"
      redis:valueSerializer-ref="redisStringSerializer"
      redis:defaultSerializer-ref="redisStringSerializer"/>
```

Note the use of `usePool=true` which prompts spring to use JedisPool. Looking through spring code also suggests that spring is handling resource allocation and release properly.

Any help identifying the issue will be appreciated.

Edit: Stack trace -

```
Thread 1:
[ERROR] [03/01/2015 07:05:32.044] [events-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2281] [akka://events-system/user/$YN/$b/$b/$b] java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.List
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getRawObjectMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:230)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getObjectMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:236)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.zscan(BinaryJedis.java:3608)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection$3.doScan(JedisConnection.java:2998)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.KeyBoundCursor.doScan(KeyBoundCursor.java:39)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.ScanCursor.scan(ScanCursor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.ScanCursor.hasNext(ScanCursor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.ConvertingCursor.hasNext(ConvertingCursor.java:56)
    ...
    application specific stack trace
    ...

Thread 2:    
[ERROR] [03/01/2015 07:03:07.295] [events-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2273] [akka://events-system/user/$VN/$b/$b/$b] Unknown redis exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Unknown redis exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.getFallback(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:48)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:38)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.zRem(JedisConnection.java:2321)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultZSetOperations$19.doInRedis(DefaultZSetOperations.java:283)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultZSetOperations$19.doInRedis(DefaultZSetOperations.java:280)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:190)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultZSetOperations.remove(DefaultZSetOperations.java:280)
    ...
    application specific stack trace
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getIntegerReply(Connection.java:210)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.zrem(BinaryJedis.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.zRem(JedisConnection.java:2319)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Any chance you can give a little more insight on what you're exactly doing, the stacktrace you have, and where you get the ClassCastExeption from? Or even better a gist or repo with a test reproducing the error...

Comment: Added stack trace from two threads to the question, I get similar error from other threads for various redis operations

Comment: did you even find a solution or cause? I am getting the same kind of exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to post an update on this here.

In my case, my analysis was that the connection pool by default used `ForkJoinPool` which works in a `work-stealing` mode. This made another thread take over the results part of the operation over and gave `ClassCastException` when there was a mismatch in Type of the result.

This did resolve the issue I had.

Comment: How did u resolved issue? faced with the same